# Zebra printing - ZPL cant rotate HEX image

Tags: image, rotation, zebra-printers, zpl

I'm currently designing some labels and the image (sent as hex) is not rotating for me when using `^FWR` command.

e.g. `^FWR^FO270,0^XGR:GHS09,1,1^FS`

Text rotates fine using this command but my image always stays as is (on its side). The code I am amending is pre-existing, so I don't want to change the orientation of the label (which would solve my issue).

The image is being sent to the printer first and is at the top of the string sent.

e.g. (I've cut out most of the image text as its 3850 chars long)

```
~DGR:GHS09,03850,022,00000000000.......etc
^XA^CFA0,30,30^FWN
^FWR^FO270,0^XGR:GHS09,1,1^FS
^FWN^PQ1^XZ
```

I am previewing the labels using labelary online tool as I dont have a zebra printer here.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried rotating the image before you convert it to hex?

Comment: ^FW only works on commands that support rotation. The ^XG command does not.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. We have gone back to the customer for pre-rotated images after spending some time trying to rotate them in code.